# How to rebel or revolt against liege?

Tags: crusader-kings-2, crusader-kings-3

Is there any way to rebel or revolt against my liege? I am playing as a prince in France and every time I click on "declare war on king" it gives me two choices, those being:

- we for de jure
- other for independence

All I want to rule the whole kingdom. Is there an option to do that in both CK2 & CK3? Is there a mode for it?

Comment: This should be split into two separate questions, since its two different games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[crusader-kings-2](/questions/tagged/crusader-kings-2) (it may also be true for CK3, I'm just not as familiar with that game.)

**Generally, if you want to go to war over a title, you first need a claim**.

You can use the "Fabricate Claim on Liege" plot to gain a claim on the Kingdom, which you can then press to take over. You can also try to inherit a claim. This would also allow you to start a faction to become ruler of the kingdom. This can give you vital allies and may even lead to you ruling without a war, if the current King accepts the demands of your faction.

There is another option that doesn't require a claim. If you control 51% or more of the counties of the kingdom, you can fight a war for independence and usurp the title afterwards (there are some more [conditions for usurpation](https://ck2.paradoxwikis.com/Title_actions#Usurp)). This will only give you the de jure title of the kingdom, all its other vassals (including the former King, assuming he held titles within the kingdom) will be released as independent counties and duchies. You will have to conquer or vassalize them separately, if you want to reunify the kingdom.

Comment: so this will work with an empire ??

Comment: If you can get a claim on the empire, you can press that claim and become emperor (whether you are a vassal or not). If you want to usurp an empire, you'll need to control 80% of it's counties (which is a significantly higher hurdle than for a kingdom).